# Model for k means clustering of last mile logsitics data set

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, clustering, k-means

I want to utilize Orange for K means clustering for Network Design for Courier Company using K means clustering. Data set includes Longitude & latitude of delivery points, parcel weight, area type that is dense or non dense, delivery date of courier, distance from warehouse to delivery point. They are both categorical and numerical data. I have 800K Delivery points. Just wanted to know if I could get assistance on how to do K means clustering on this data set and how to interpret output. I am going to learn here from scratch. Let me know if I can connect and work on my project.